# When adding a ChannelHandler with a DefaultEventExecutorGroup, can its code block?

Tags: netty

The [three-argument form of `ChannelPipeline#addLast()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html#addLast-io.netty.util.concurrent.EventExecutorGroup-java.lang.String-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler-) accepts an `EventExecutorGroup` as its first argument.  This method is frequently cited as a way to work with synchronous code: pass a new instance of [`DefaultEventExecutorGroup`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultEventExecutorGroup.html) and you are all set.

If code run in a `ChannelHandler` added this way blocks, that will block a thread from the `DefaultEventExecutorGroup` passed in at `addLast()` time, right?  And not any thread that Netty may be using to communicate with a `ServerSocket`?

If so, does that mean that `ChannelHandlerContext#write()` invoked from within such a handler will also behave properly?  Or will writes be potentially out of sequence since they are originating from potentially different threads?  Is there a preferred way to perform writes from within a `ChannelHandler` added in this way?

Finally, what will the value of `channelHandlerContext.executor().inEventLoop()` be in such a `ChannelHandler` added this way?  I am guessing that it will return `false`.